# Official build of Chromium web browser

Tags: chromium

Are there any "official" (meaning trustworthy) builds of Chromium for Windows? I am not interested in Google Chrome, which has branding/spying modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you wanted: If you can't find Chromium, there's an unofficial build/fork called [Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php). (Source code's at the bottom of the download page.)

Iron strips out the branding/spying modules and has a "portable apps" install which means you can install it even if the normal Chrome Installer can't reach the internet.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are not. You will have to compile Chromium from source.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not official build, but maintened by Chromium Team.
https://download-chromium.appspot.com/

You should be aware these are, as the description says, "raw" builds from the most recent version of the source trunk, and may be significantly less stable than the packaged builds you may be used to of Chromium for Linux distributions or of Chrome.